# Trying to convert string to proper format / encoding?

Tags: c#, string, encoding, character

I have a program that does some screen scraping of a French language web page and finds a specific string.  Once found I take that string and save it.  The returned string shows up as `User does not have a desktop configured.` or in French as `L'utilisateur ne dispose pas d'un bureau configuré.`, but actually shows up as: `L**\x26#39**;utilisateur ne dispose pas d**\x26#39**;un bureau configur**�**.`  How can I get it to consider the `\x26#39` as the apostrophe `'` character.

Is there something in C# that I can use to read the Url and return the correct phrase.

I have looked an many available C# capabilities, but cannot find one that will provide me with the correct result.

Sample code tried playing with:

```
// translated the true French text to English to help out with this example.
// 
Encoding winVar1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;

string url = String.Format("http://www.My-TEST-SITE.com/);
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
cVar = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("Search_TEXT=")).Length ;
result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("Search_TEXT="),  cVar);
result = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(result);
result = WebUtility.UrlDecode(result);
result = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf("Found: "));
```

This returns `L**\x26#39**;utilisateur ne dispose pas d**\x26#39**;un bureau configur**�**.`
when it should return:  `L'utilisateur ne dispose pas d'un bureau configuré.`.

I am trying to get rid of the `\x26#39` and get the proper French characters to show as `é ê è ç â` etc.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to use proper tool like HtmlAgilityPack for web scarping?

Comment: You're mixing a lot of things together. Basically, UTF8 is the way characters are encoded, and Unicode the representation. I suggest you to read first this amazing post about that and you will understand what's going on. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: I was not aware about "HtmlAgilityPack", reading documentation now.  As for the Joel site...yes I have seen it, but it does not tell me why I am still seeing none UTF8 codes in my screen scrap.  Trying to find the perfect code to get me the correct text.

Comment: @MaximilianoRios - Plus 1 for the article link.

Comment: You're welcome, I think we all should read these kind of articles about the background of this matter. It's very important to understand to code properly.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSunders, I stand corrected.  Thank you

Comment: So if I understand some part of Joel article and the documentation from "HtmlAgilityPack"; I should be able to do what I want by interpreting the screen scrap via UTF8 and in worse case use "windows-1252" for the French stuff.  But there is a missing link that is simply not providing me the code required.  what am I missing...  any clues as to what I should be using? and How?

Comment: It sounds like you are saving the bytes just fine.  The program you are using to display the string needs to be told what encoding to use.  Maybe it is on the web page in a meta tag; I read the article and am now an expert!

Comment: @SteveWellens the web page states: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"

Comment: @user3147056 I felt brave enough to post an suggested answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm can't be sure but:

```
result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("Search_TEXT="),  cVar);
result = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(result);
result = WebUtility.UrlDecode(result);
```

Double decoding the text can't be good.  It's either a URL or HTML or neither.  Not both.

Comment: tried:    result = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(result);
  //  result = WebUtility.UrlDecode(result);   then     // result = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(result);
    result = WebUtility.UrlDecode(result);  the UrlDecode alone gave me an error on size of string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your first issue is not with character encoding, but with someone's custom combination of an ["\x" escaped sequence](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/strings.aspx) and obscured [html entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_entity#Character_reference_overview).

That funny `**\x26#39**;` is actually just a simple single quote. The translated hex character `\x26` becomes `&` so you get `**&#39**;`. Remove the extraneous stars and you get the html entity `&#39;`. With *HtmlDecode* this becomes the simple apostrophe, `'`, which is just ascii character 39.

Try out this snippet. Note that only the last step are we able to do an HtmlDecode.

```
var input = @"L**\x26#39**;utilisateur ne dispose pas d**\x26#39**;un bureau configur**�**";

var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\*\*([^*]*)\*\*", "$1");  // Take out the extra stars 

// Unescape \x values
result = Regex.Replace(result,
                       @"\\x([a-fA-F0-9]{2})",
                       match => char.ConvertFromUtf32(Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value,
                                                                  System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)));

// Decode html entities
result = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(result);
```

The output is `L'utilisateur ne dispose pas d'un bureau configur�`

The second issue is with accented "e". That actually is an encoding issue and you'll probably have to keep playing around with it to get it right. You might want to also try *UTF16* or even *UTF32*. But HtmlAgilityPack might just take care of this for you automatically.